# MyEclipse Professional on connecting with ms sql server is giving ssl error through db browser

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, jdbc

I am using MyEclipse professional and trying to connect with the MS SQL SERVER 2016, i am using the jar file sqljdbc4-4.0 and driver
“class name= com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver”
My connection URL is jdbc:sqlserver://hamdan:1433;databaseName=DWProject
where hamdan is the SQL server name, after giving the credentials i got the error of error while performing database login with the mysqlserver driver: the driver couldn't establish a secure connection to SQL server by using secure socket layer(SSL) encryption. Error java.lang.runtimeException, could not generate DH keypair.

---

However i have also set Force Encryption to "NO" in the protocol for sql server's properties in sql server configuration.
when i am changing the jar with the jar present on this link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774 which is jdbc 6.0 and using jar for jre 8 which is sqljdbc42, i get error of driver class not found while using new database connection driver.
Any help will be highly appreciated, i am on this from more than one day,
I am new to eclipse.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem in windows 10, it encrypts the link between eclipse and SQL Server, so you should use latest myeclipse or try in different OS